# Am I alone or the font of the site is changed?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I realized the font of question titles and score numbers are bigger than before. Am I alone or does anyone experience the same thing? When you want to start writing your question you see it as well.

In meta it is not like that.

If that's the new policy are you ok with it?

[image: Site font]

Comment: The site doesn't look different to me; what operating system and browser are you using?

Comment: I am on iOS (16.5.1) using Firefox Focus (v115.0) and am seeing the same enlarged fonts on the main site. Going to my laptop, Vivaldi (6.1.3035.204) and Brave (v1.56.11) both look fine.

Comment: And though I didn't make an exhaustive check, I went to several other SE sites via HNQ and did not find the enlarged fonts.

Comment: [Here is a link to what I see on Firefox Focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8fiq.jpg) and [what I see on Academia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlzVI.jpg) still using Firefox Focus which doesn't seem to have the problem.

Comment: Scratch that [math.se] also has big fonts on the same setup above. I wonder if maybe MathJax had an update for some mobile devices that is causing it?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I'm using Google Chrome for Android mobile phone.

Comment: @KyleKanos Even the bolded parts of answers are enlarged!

Comment: [Math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35886/has-mathstackexchange-changed-its-font-size) and [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391579/mobile-font-size-way-too-large) questions regarding the matter.

Comment: I see the same, on Firefox for Android.

Comment: I see the same on Chrome on Android.

Comment: Firefox Focus got the patch today & I'm very glad it did so, as it was rather distracting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug, [confirmed fixed on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391582/380389). It may take a few days for the fix to appear on different sites due to caching.

Comment: It wasn't a problem on Meta.SE. It was just asked there.

Comment: @SnackExchange To be clear, the confirmation was posted on Meta.SE. I don't mean that they only fixed it there.

Comment: I thought he said we are working on a fixing.

Comment: @SnackExchange "This bug has been patched in our design system and the update has been shipped to production."